# hostapd client associates, does not receive IP address

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge, hostapd

I'm trying to set up my raspberry pi to use a realtek 8192eu wireless card but without much luck. I have compiled hostapd and the 8192eu driver. The bridge is set up using /etc/network/interfaces; the Access Point is created and clients can successfully associate. But they voluntarily disassociate a few minutes later and are never assigned an IP address. I *think* that means that DHCP requests are not being transferred through the bridge.

```
root@walle:/home/xbian# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# wireless wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

# eth0 connected to the ISP router
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# Setup bridge
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    ## isp router ip, 192.168.1.2 also runs DHCPD ##
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1




root@walle:/home/xbian# cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
# Basic configuration

interface=wlan0
ssid=wallesap
channel=1
bridge=br0

# WPA and WPA2 configuration

macaddr_acl=0
#auth_algs=1
#ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
#wpa=3
#wpa_passphrase=12345678
#wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#wpa_pairwise=TKIP
#rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Hardware configuration
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g




root@walle:/home/xbian# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"wallesap"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
        Mode:Master  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:13:EF:35:14:03   
        Bit Rate:144.4 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
        Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
        Encryption key:off
        Power Management:off
        Link Quality=4/100  Signal level=4/100  Noise level=0/100
        Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
        Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
root@walle:/home/xbian# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:27:EB:19:6F:E7  
        inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe19:6fe7/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:726 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:64454 (62.9 KiB)  TX bytes:72419 (70.7 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:27:EB:19:6F:E7  
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:69329 (67.7 KiB)  TX bytes:78563 (76.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:4022 (3.9 KiB)  TX bytes:4022 (3.9 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:EF:35:14:03  
        inet6 addr: fe80::213:efff:fe35:1403/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:2570 (2.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1632 (1.5 KiB)


root@walle:/home/xbian# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

In desperation I have even tried installing dnsmasq and configuring it to hand out addresses on wlan0 but without any luck.

Edit: Later, I tried enabling promiscuous mode on wlan0:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:EF:35:14:03  
      inet6 addr: fe80::213:efff:fe35:1403/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2336 (2.2 KiB)  TX bytes:1632 (1.5 KiB)
```

As you can see, traffic appears to be flowing over the card but it doesn't seem to make a difference to the problem. Perhaps the bridge needs to promiscuous too?

On the AP side, here is the dmesg output:

```
[23201.874218] RTL871X: +OnAuth
[23201.874241] RTL871X: auth alg=0, seq=1
[23201.874253] RTL871X: going to alloc stainfo for sa=34:02:86:a1:8c:9f
[23201.874271] RTL871X: rtw_alloc_macid = 0
[23201.874288] RTL871X: issue_auth
[23201.878507] RTL871X: OnAssocReq
[23201.878522] RTL871X: IEEE 802.11 element parse ignored unknown element (id=127 elen=8)
[23201.878535] RTL871X: STA did not include WPA/RSN IE in (Re)Association Request - possible WPS use
[23201.878545] RTL871X: allocate new AID = (1)
[23201.878558] RTL871X: HT: STA 34:02:86:a1:8c:9f HT Capabilities Info: 0x11a5
[23201.878569] RTL871X: bss_cap_update_on_sta_join STA 34:02:86:a1:8c:9f - no greenfield, num of non-gf stations 1
[23201.878579] RTL871X: bss_cap_update_on_sta_join STA 34:02:86:a1:8c:9f - 20 MHz HT, num of 20MHz HT STAs 1
[23201.878587] RTL871X: bss_cap_update_on_sta_join, updated=0
[23201.878594] RTL871X: update_sta_info_apmode
[23201.878600] RTL871X: ### Set STA_(0) info
[23201.878612] RTL871X: issue_asocrsp
[23201.878642] RTL871X: report_add_sta_event: add STA
[23201.878725] RTL871X: ### rtl8192e_set_FwMediaStatus_cmd: MStatus=1 MACID=0 
[23201.879306] RTL871X: add_RATid=> mac_id:0 , raid:2 , shortGIrate=0, bitmap=0xfffffff
[23201.879318] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_raid_cmd, bitmap=0xfffffff, mac_id=0x0, raid=0x2, shortGIrate=0
[23201.880294] RTL871X: indicate_sta_assoc_event to upper layer - hostapd
[23201.880303] RTL871X: +rtw_indicate_sta_assoc_event
[23201.880474] RTL871X: rtw_get_sta_wpaie, sta_addr: 34:02:86:a1:8c:9f
[23201.880485] RTL871X: sta's wpa_ie is NONE
[23203.533749] RTL871X: add_RATid=> mac_id:0 , raid:2 , shortGIrate=0, bitmap=0xfffffff
[23203.533770] RTL871X: rtl8192e_set_raid_cmd, bitmap=0xf8ff000, mac_id=0x0, raid=0x2, shortGIrate=0
[23219.567406] RTL871X: issue_nulldata(wlan0) to 34:02:86:a1:8c:9f, ch:1, 1/1 in 6 ms
[23219.567425] RTL871X: ack check for asoc expire, keep_alive_trycnt=1
[23219.622116] RTL871X: wakeup_sta_to_xmit alive check
[23227.583586] RTL871X: issue_nulldata(wlan0) to 34:02:86:a1:8c:9f, ch:1, 1/1 in 6 ms
[23227.583604] RTL871X: ack check for asoc expire, keep_alive_trycnt=1
[23227.609353] RTL871X: wakeup_sta_to_xmit alive check
```

This definitely looks like a successful association attempt.

And this from the wireless client:

```
[25663.895131] wlo1: authenticate with 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2
[25663.901055] wlo1: send auth to 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (try 1/3)
[25663.928925] wlo1: authenticated
[25663.929530] wlo1: associate with 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (try 1/3)
[25663.987682] wlo1: associate with 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (try 2/3)
[25663.988717] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=3)
[25663.990808] wlo1: associated
[25712.996257] wlo1: deauthenticating from 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[25713.017426] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[25713.017430] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[25713.017432] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[25713.017435] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.017438] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.017440] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.017442] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.017445] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[25713.017447] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[25713.017449] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.017451] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.021207] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
[25713.021210] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[25713.021211] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[25713.021213] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.021214] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[25713.021216] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[25713.021217] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[25713.021218] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[25738.000665] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[25750.500907] wlo1: authenticate with 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2
[25750.506858] wlo1: direct probe to 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (try 1/3)
[25750.710295] wlo1: direct probe to 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (try 2/3)
[25750.913310] wlo1: direct probe to 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 (try 3/3)
[25751.114337] wlo1: authentication with 2c:b0:5d:cc:db:e2 timed out

    [25763.024159] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
```

So again, that looks like a successful association event followed by the client choosing to disconnect. Why would it do that? Possibly because it receives no DHCP lease in time?

Comment: I haven't done this on Linux before, but it seems to me that for interfaces to be part of a bridge, they would need to be in promiscuous mode, and I don't see that in the interface flags in the ifconfig output.

Comment: Excellent point. I did consider that but I couldn't figure out how to set it permanently. I have amended my question accordingly.